# gcc: warning: pf_xmit.o: linker input file unused because linking not done in linux

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linker-errors

I am trying to write a simple makefile in ubuntu. My makefile is shown below.  When I execute `make`, I get the linker error shown in the title. Can anyone provide guidance about this error or tell me if there is a better approach? Basically, I have a few .h and .c files and need to compile and execute them.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
RM = @rm -f
DEPS = pub.h main.h common.h p_pub.h udp_pub.h
OBJ = opts.o pf_ctrl.o pf_recv.o pf_xmit.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
$(CC) -c $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean: $(RM) $(OBJ)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using -c in your CFLAGS which tells GCC not to link, only compile objects.  remove $(CFLAGS) from the last line in your makefile

```
hellomake: $(OBJ)
gcc -o $@ $^
```